# TUI flight TOM672 25th May 2019

Tags: air-travel

Do you have information to confirm that flight TOM672 from Manchester to Dalaman departing at 15.15 did happen. I was booked on that flight and was told it had been cancelled and was placed on a much later flight. 
I was notified by somebody who travelled on that day that they did fly on that flight and it wasn't cancelled.
I need confirmation of this then I can challenge TUI about it

Answer (score 0):

According to FlightRadar, the flight did happen although it set off over 2 hours late, at 17:30 instead of the planned 15:15

https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/by672#20a52c50

Comment: Hmm, it shows a 16:16 departure for me. (And Flightradar24 doesn't tell -- or know -- whether the flight carried passengers).

Comment: The Flightradar data also seems to show that the flight is _planned_ for a 737 MAX 8, but was actually carried out with a 737-800. If the latter has fewer seats, it would have been necessary to bump off some passengers.